# If a crewmate disconnects/quits, are you then automatically screwed on tasks?

Tags: among-us

If a crewmate leaves the server before ending his tasks, are you then completely screwed and can't win via tasks?

Or is there a system in place that would make that if a crewmate leaves, his tasks are not counted in the 'win via tasks' bar?

If so: Could it be a strategy  that if you know you are the last crewmate with tasks, you can disconnect to give the win to the crewmates?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a crewmate disconnects during a game, their remaining tasks are deducted from the task bar. So, yes, if you are the last player with tasks, you could disconnect and have the crewmates win.

Source: personal experience. Had a player disconnect who had quite a few tasks left and noticed the bar was changed and we were able to get a task win shortly thereafter.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but if there’s the same number of imposters as crewmates, the imposters win correct? So, Follow-up question: if there’s 4 crewmates and 3 of the 4 crewmates have their tasks done, and there’s 3 imposters, if the crewmate that doesn’t have their tasks done leaves, do the crewmates or imposters win?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the amount of crewmates left, having a crewmate disconnect can cause different results. If one more crewmate needed to be killed by the impostor to win, the impostor will win the match if the crewmate disconnects (I think the same happens if one crewmate needs to be killed to win and that last crewmate has the last task(s), if the crewmate disconnects the impostor will win instead of the crewmates). Sometimes the opposite happens where the crewmate disconnecting causes the crewmates to win since the tasks become completed.